# AngularJS - How to refer to a submodule controller from ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm struggling a bit with having submodules in an Angular 1.3.9 app. I've got a (non-working, sorry) preview at http://plnkr.co/edit/XBfTPAGRRe0CWJgjGJzc?p=preview and I think it's freaking out, in part, because I'm using Restangular.

I have the following:

```js
angular
    .module('estimate', ['ui.router', 'restangular', 'estimate.project'])
;

angular
.module('estimate.project', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'
        , function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
       .state('project', {
            url: "/project/{id:int}",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: '/app/templates/project.html',
            controller: "ProjectController as project", 
            resolve: { // stuff }
        })
        .state('project.overview', {
            url: "",
            templateUrl: "/app/templates/overview.html"
        })
        // ...
    ;
}])
.controller('ProjectController', ['$scope', 'ProjectService', 'myProject'
          , function($scope, ProjectService, myProject) {

    console.log('i made it!');

}]);
```

And in my template, which is served from the `estimate` module, I have:

```
<li><a ui-sref="project.overview({ id: 1 })">One</a></li>
```

The URL resolves correctly on the page, but clicking on it does nothing. It doesn't even throw any console errors - it just sits there. My gut tells me it has to do with how I'm referring to the controllers and/or the routes, and if they need to be prefixed or modified to work with a submodule. Any ideas on how to get it to load properly?

If this post is too scatterbrained, let me know and I'll try to clean it up.

Comment: Actually throws error module estimate not defined.

Comment: It looks like it was getting thrown off by the `base href="/"` at the top. I've fixed it, and it at least loads now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [updated your plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VMIo0LmyE53ODoEIeGUZ?p=preview) and would say, that the most important change is - referencing ***sub-module*** in the **main module**:

Instead of this:

```
angular
    .module('estimate', ['ui.router', 'restangular'])
    ...

angular
    .module('estimate.project', ['ui.router'])
    ...
```

We have to use this, i.e. reference sub module in a parent module

```
angular
    .module('estimate', ['ui.router', 'restangular', 'estimate.project'])
    ...

angular
    .module('estimate.project', ['ui.router'])
    ...
```

With some few other small adjustments, that should be **the way**. Check it working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VMIo0LmyE53ODoEIeGUZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Radim, that helps. When I bring all the different modules together in one file, it does work. I guess my issue is in splitting it up into multiple files.

For the plunker, I crammed everything into one file; in my code, though, I have different files and am `require()`ing one into another. I wonder if it was just an issue in how those files are being included..

Comment: Well, there could be more files... that is absolutely ok. I do have many files. the point is, that the main module - must load others.. MUST ;) good luck with UI-Router

Comment: I took your plunker update and broke it down into modules, carefully controlling when `angular.module()` got called for the main and submodules, and it worked. It was just some breakdown in how and where the initial `.module()` got called. Thanks again.